# How to get main HWND of exe from dll in c++

Tags: c++, winapi, dll

I'm trying to get my EXE's hwnd so I can get title of HWND.

I've already tried the below, but it is printing blank. (Dll code)

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumThreadWndProc(HWND argHwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    *(HWND *)lParam = argHwnd;
    return FALSE;
}
```

---

```
char retbuff[1024];
memset(retbuff, 0, sizeof(char) * 1024);
HWND handle;
DWORD lThreadId = GetCurrentThreadId();
EnumThreadWindows(lThreadId, EnumThreadWndProc, (long)&handle);
GetWindowTextA(handle, retbuff, 1023);
std::string windowName(retbuff);
std::wstring stemp = s2ws(windowName); // Temporary buffer is required
LPCWSTR result = stemp.c_str();

MessageBox(0, L"aaa.", result, 0);  // Use good old Message Box inside Windows Api Functions but this time with your own dll }
```

And I found out when I was looking for solutions that I can get HINSTANCE of EXE from dll by using something as the following:

```
HINSTANCE exe = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
```

- Can I use that for my purpose ?

Comment: "EXEs" don't have "hWnds". Do you mean `hInstance` of the entry-executable? Or do you mean the `hWnd` of the current foreground window of a process?

Comment: Why don't you already know your main window handle? Presumably you created it.

Comment: How can I get main window handle that's the point. How can I know as I said It's being created in EXE not in DLL.  I want to get current foreground window created by exe.

Comment: Maybe try FindWindow then? Seems much easier to just pass the handle to your DLL from the EXE.

Comment: I can do that but window name is changing like "test 1","test 2","test 3" i need to check if test is changed or not. If there is no test in title I want to return false

Comment: Post the code for `EnumThreadWndProc` then. You should not be casting `&handle` to `long` as this will break on 64-bit Windows.

Comment: How do you know the window you're looking for belongs to the current thread?

Comment: Added EnumThreadWndProc to main post. 

@CaptainObvlious I actually dont

Comment: @SarpAykent: Then you will have to use `EnumWindows()` instead of `EnumThreadWindows()`, where the callback uses `GetWindowThreadProcessId()` to ignore `HWND`s that do not belong to the calling process.  But then, the EXE may have multiple `HWND`s, so how do you know which one is the right one?  You would have to look at each `HWND`'s title and/or class name, or some other unique identifier in the `HWND` itself, until you find what you are looking for. The easiest solution is to simply export a function for the EXE to call to pass its `HWND` to your DLL, then you don't have to hunt for it.

Comment: You're not testing for anything in your enum callback, just returning the first window found.

Comment: You keep ignoring all the important comments. Consider that the exe creates multiple top level windows. Which one do you want to find?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I will try to do like that Making BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hwnd, LONG lParam) and using EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc, (LPARAM)0); like send every windows right ?

Comment: @JonathanPotter I'm trying to but this function I paste just finding 1 window

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes I got that.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that `EnumWindowsProc` takes a `LONG` parameter?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/CPP/Q_21838863.html

Comment: Well, it's not a `LONG`. You should consult the documentation.